# Mouse input not being released from other process's window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, overlay

I am writing a C++ Windows program that displays game stats/friends info over games using a Win32 window and a DirectX11 renderer. (that renders a UI that is controlled with the mouse and keyboard)

The window is overlaid on top of the game’s window and has the flags **WS_EX_TRANSPARENT** and **WS_POPUP** set.
When the window is activated, I set **WS_EX_LAYERED** to capture inputs.

The created window is positioned on top of the target window if GetWindow(target_, GW_HWNDPREV) is different from the handle of the created window.
It is placed on top of it by calling SetWindowPos with SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS.

I’ve double-checked that the flags are set correctly and that the functions are being called.
I also tried using ShowWindow with the SW_SHOW flag, but the result remained unchanged.

I’m currently running my tests on Portal 2, but ideally, I would want this to work on the majority of games. (OS used is Windows 11 22H2)

To activate the window and release the mouse capture from the game, I am calling SetForegroundWindow, SetActiveWindow, and SetFocus, all with the HWND of my window.
This approach **works correctly when I run the program from Visual Studio**, but when I run the compiled executable, the mouse remains locked in the game.

Both builds were tested in debug and release mode, and I really can't figure out why this is happening.

```cpp
LRESULT Renderer::WndProc(...) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_SIZE:
        // resize buffers and recreate render target view
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(handle, message, w_param, l_param);
}

bool Window::Create(...) {
    // ...
    hwnd_ = CreateWindowEx(
        wndclass,
        class_name_.c_str(),
        title_.c_str(),
        WS_POPUP,
        0, 0, 10, 10,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr
    );

    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd_, 0, 255, LWA_ALPHA);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd_);

    constexpr MARGINS margin = {-1, -1, -1, -1};
    const auto result = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd_, &margin);
    
    // ...
}

void Window::Activate() {
    // Remove the WS_EX_LAYERED attribute.
    SetClickThrough(false);

    SetForegroundWindow(hwnd_);
    SetActiveWindow(hwnd_);
    SetFocus(hwnd_);
}

// ----------------------
// Sample main routine pseudocode:
// ----------------------

renderer->window.Create(...);
while (renderer->is_running()) {
    renderer->BeginFrame();

    // Position the window on top of the game found.
    renderer->window().FollowTarget();

    // Toggle the visibility using the F2 key.
    // If transitioning from hidden to visible, call the window
    // activation routine.
    if (utils::KeyPressed(VK_F2)) {
        if (ui->is_visible()) {
            // .. window deactivation not included
            ui->set_visible(false);
        }
        else {
            renderer->window().Activate();
            ui->set_visible(true);
        }
    }   

    ui->Draw(renderer);
    renderer->Present();
}
```

*I considered using a low-level keyboard/mouse hook to capture inputs, or offscreen rendering and presenting it in the game using a DirectX hook, but I’d rather avoid it as it would require many games to manually whitelist it.*

Is there something else I’m missing or a different approach I should be taking?

Comment: I'm not sure what *When the window is activated, I set WS_EX_LAYERED to capture inputs* means. `WS_EX_LAYERED` is for making your window (or part of your window) transparent or transluscent. It's not for capturing mouse input. You haven't shown the `SetClickThrough` function so I can't tell if this is really what you meant or not.

Comment: To capture input, have you tried [`SetCapture()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcapture) yet? On the other hand, do you really need to capture input away from the game that the user is playing? Or, do you just want to process when the mouse is within your window while input focus stays in the game? I'm not really sure what your goal is here. Also, why aren't you creating your overlay window as a topmost (stay-on-top) window?

Comment: @JonathanPotter SetClickThrough basically just removes or adds the WS_EX_LAYERED flag to GWL_EXSTYLE.
If WS_EX_LAYERED is set, the window allows clicks to pass through it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried using `SetCapture()`, but it does not help.
MSDN: `If the mouse cursor is over a window created by another thread, the system will direct mouse input to the specified window only if a mouse button is down.`
I need to capture the input exclusively, because I want users to be able to interact with the UI.
The focus can shift from the game to my window, it's not an issue.
I'm not using topmost because it would position it always on top of any window. Manually placing it after the target results in the overlay always looking on top of it, while below other windows.

Comment: @BrianPx82 "*If WS_EX_LAYERED is set, the window allows clicks to pass through it.. I need to capture the input exclusively, because I want users to be able to interact with the UI*" - this seems kind of contradictory to me. I don't understand what your goal is, please clarify.

Comment: @RemyLebeau My goal is to make a window that always stays on top of a game. If multiple games are running at the same time, multiple windows are created and each one follows its target.
These windows show an interactive UI, and the user should be able to interact with it if said UI is visible.
If it is not visible, only notifications are shown and the user should be able to interact with the game as if the overlay didn't exist.

This method is quite solid and has been used by many for years, but the real issue is the fact that if I set my window to be active (to steal focus from ---

Comment: --- the game), the cursor stays locked in the game.
I want it to get released, so an user can interact with the overlay window.
The weird thing is that this approach works perfectly in the PoC I made, but only if run from Visual Studio. If I start it from the compiled executable the cursor stays locked in the game.

Comment: To get a handle to the capture window on another thread, use the [GetGUIThreadInfo][1] function, then try using GetCapture.


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getguithreadinfo